# Uploading file using Httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, html

I want to upload file to a server. I wrote this function to upload the file to localhost server (I am using wamp server):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Albert\Documents\10050409_3276.doc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/upload_file");
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentLength = fstream.Length;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] indata = new byte[1024];
        int bytes_read = fstream.Read(indata, 0, indata.Length);
        while (bytes_read > 0)
        {
            request_stream.Write(indata, 0, indata.Length);
            bytes_read = fstream.Read(indata, 0, indata.Length);
        }
        fstream.Close();
        request_stream.Close();
        request.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    }
```

So when i click on the button the exception apper said that:

> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

I tried to use "POST" instead of "PUT" so the program works and the message box appears to say 'ok', but when i open the localhost->upload_file(folder) Ididn't find any files.

I tested my program with wamp server => the problem occured.

I tested my program with real server and put in the network credentials and tried to upload to folder that has (777) permission => the problem occured.

So where is the problem exactly?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you're missing the Multipart Mime type.  And you'll definitely need to use "POST" unless you specifically created a website that allows the "PUT" method.

Answer (score 2):

try with webClient

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
 byte[] bret = client.UploadFile(path, "POST", FilePath);
//path==URL
//FilePath==Your uploading file path
```

or

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
string webAddress = null; 
try 
{ 
    webAddress = @"http://localhost/upload_file/"; 

    webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 

    WebRequest serverRequest = WebRequest.Create(webAddress); 
    serverRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebResponse serverResponse; 
    serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse(); 
    serverResponse.Close(); 

    webClient.UploadFile(path, "POST", FilePath); 
    webClient.Dispose(); 
    webClient = null; 
} 
catch (Exception error) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message); 
}
```

(code in or part i didn't tried )

Comment: WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] bret = client.UploadFile("http://localhost/Lecture Fetcher/xml_files", "POST", "k.xml");
Console.WriteLine("ok");

Comment: the consol write (ok) but when i open the xml_files (folder) there isn't any file exist

Comment: al things is right but there isn't any file have exist in the upload file (floder)

Comment: try using files: FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(filePath));

fileInfo.CopyTo(path);